# can undefined behaviour in C on codeblocks(debug mode) corrupt files on my pc?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

My question is: is it possible for a C program running in debug mode on codeblocks to delete important data on my computer? (like when changing the value of a pointer rather then the value it points to and then dereferencing it)

Comment: Theoretically!? UB behavior means malicious code can run. Practically pointers don't point to your hard drive. So if you write to a memory location (even an unspecified one) you won't damage your files.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think you meant to post that under my answer, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh - Not really. The OP seems worried their files will go missing. I was trying to reassure them that the file system is separate from the memory space of a process (malicious code that is invoked because of UB and deleting files notwithstanding).

Comment: @StoryTeller if I alter the value at a memory address in the central memory and that happens to be a valid instruction that performs an output operation on the hard drive I guess even that is possible, right?

Comment: @MatSiv97 - Are you in a hosted environment? The OS is there to protect you from such a thing. If you have direct and unrestricted access to memory, then all bets are off.

Comment: @StoryTeller my apple 2 has memory mapped IO and no MMU  You can delete the entire disk by writing to the wrong memory address.

Answer (score 5):

Undefined behaviour is undefined. It can do weird things.

Theoretically, it can corrupt ***any*** memory location. Side effects range from ignorable to catastrophic actions.

Read this [very related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire) wiki article.

Answer (score 2):

It entirely depends on what your code does and what kind of undefined behavior you are referring to. Code like this could theoretically damage files on your computer:

```
char* garbage; // not initialized
FILE* fp = fopen(garbage, "w");
fprintf(fp, "hello");
```